# Civilization 5 keeps crashing - invalid reference

Tags: technical-issues, civilization-5

Looking in the logs files specifically Database.log, I keep seeing this error:

```
[417084.850] constraint failed
[417084.850] While executing - 'INSERT INTO ArtDefine_StrategicView(StrategicViewType, TileType, Asset) VALUES(?,?,?)'
[417094.444] no such table: ContentPackage.LocalizedText
[417097.470] Validating Foreign Key Constraints...
[417097.486] Invalid Reference on ArtDefine_Landmarks.LayoutHandler - "SPECIAL" does not exist in ArtDefine_LandmarkTypes
[417097.486] Invalid Reference on ArtDefine_Landmarks.LayoutHandler - "SPECIAL" does not exist in ArtDefine_LandmarkTypes
[417097.486] Invalid Reference on ArtDefine_Landmarks.LayoutHandler - "SPECIAL" does not exist in ArtDefine_LandmarkTypes
[417098.640] Invalid Reference on UnitGameplay2DScripts.UnitType - "UNIT_PRIVATEER" does not exist in Units
[417098.640] Failed Validation.
```

I bought the game of the year edition from Steam, and I'm not using any mods. Does anyone know how to fix this error?

Comment: In your game library, right click on the game, open `Properties`, go to the `Local Files` tab, and click `Verify Integrity of Game Cache`. See if that helps.

Comment: I do that and it fixes it temporarily, but then after a while the same crash comes again.

Comment: Are your graphics drivers up to date?

Comment: yeah, they are up to date

Comment: Looks like the game database on MSSQLExpress is corrupt/ not created properly. This was probably due to a faulty install. As bad as this may sound try a re-install. If it helps you take backup of some of the files, and restore them by pausing th e download, but you probably have to figure which is the mdf database file that needs fixing and let it go through the normal install process.